# AgilityPack Select innerText but skip specific tag

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Regarding an exemple like this :

```
<p>there is something here <span>we can't have this</span> again here <em>but we keep this one</em> we are good to go now </p>
```

I have a way to delete the span node so I can get only the inner text of all other tag. But I need to keep the span tag but skip his innerText when I get it. For now I have this :

```
var paragraphe = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("p");
for (int i = 0; i < paragraphe.Count; i++)
{
    string innerTextOfP = paragraphe[i].InnerText;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerTextOfP))
    {
        //Do something later.
    }
    else
    {
        //something is done here with the text I get.
    }
}
```

The best way I can figure is to have another thing like :

```
var nodeSpan = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("span");
```

And compare it while I Iterate on the children of the P section with a string buffer to get the text and skip the content if `paragraphe.childNode = nodeSpan` But I think Agility Pack have another way to do this kind of stuff but I don't know what.

In my case I also need to skip the content of a DIV (and his children) if the classe is other then `"contenu"`

So the way I was going to do it for the Span my be not good for the DIV part.

How should I do it witht he agilityPack?

Edit : the expected result for this case would be :

```
string innerTextOfP = "there is something here again here but we keep this one we are good to go now"
```

Comment: Can you please provide expected result instead of describing it?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I'll edit to add the expected result.

Comment: First, in the html itself, you could give the unwanted `span` a class, say `<span class="unwanted">`. Then, later remove all child nodes of `span[@class='unwanted']`and _then_ read the inner text. That an option?

Comment: @LocEngineer I can't add class to the span, I am not responsable of this part, I need to find a way with the thing I got from other, BTW I don't want to remove the tag, I need to keep it just to skip it's innerText

Comment: OK, then you need a way to identify that part. If you don't want to remove the node, simply remove it from a clone of the node... if it always a span, you could use a version of the answers below. If not, you need some other way to tell your code which is the unwanted child node.

Comment: @LocEngineer, yeah I  did not know about the clone thing, but indeed, I can work on a clone version then use the modification on the main node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `span` children from paragraph:

```
var paragraphes = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");

foreach (var p in paragraphes)
{
    var clone = p.Clone(); // to avoid modification of original html
    foreach (var span in clone.SelectNodes("span"))
        clone.RemoveChild(span);

    foreach (var div in clone.SelectNodes("div[not(@class='contenu')]"))
        clone.RemoveChild(div);

    // remove other nodes which you want to skip here

    string innerTextOfP = Regex.Replace(clone.InnerText, @"\s+", " ");
}
```

Note that I'm using regular expression to replace several consecutive white spaces with one white space. Output is:

> there is something here again here but we keep this one we are good to
>   go now

Comment: He wants also to remove the <em> tag with the content of it.

Comment: @mybirthname no, OP wants to keep content of `em` tag. See his expected result

Comment: As I said in my question, I don't want to remove them I have already a way to do so, I just want to skip them when I get the innerText, not remove them from the document.

Comment: @Slayner ok, got u. Just clone paragraph if you don't want to modify original html

Comment: @mybirthname I don't remove the tag, the expected result is the innerText of my exemple, no remove should be done on any tag, only skip the inner text of the span

Comment: yeah but, if i clone it, I won't be able to change it from the main htmlDocument I got after I work on them ?

Comment: @mybirthname for the 3rd time, and as it is written in the question : this is InnerText not InnerHtml.

Comment: Ho I see, If I clone the node I can work on it then use it to compare with the main one an modify the main one as I want, Thanks.